# Is there an interactive output device to view 3D graphs in R?

Tags: r, 3d, plot, interactive

I'm currently generating 3D graphs in R using the `persp`-command. To change the viewpoint one has to set the parameters `theta` and `phi`. To evaluate (a good viewpoint on) the graph, one has to try lots of combinations for these parameters.

I was wondering if one can define an interactive output device that allows to rotate the graph using the mouse. It would be also nice if this device gives the current values for `theta` and `phi`.

Is there such a device/package?

Comment: Have a look at the rgl package: http://rgl.neoscientists.org/about.shtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the **rgl** package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html

It won't report the `theta` and `phi` values you need, IIRC (though see @Dieter's comment below for a solution to this), but you can use `rgl.snapshot()` or `rgl.postscript()` to grab the current display as a bitmap or vector image. The package has `persp3d()` which is very similar to `persp()`.

Comment: While you do not get angles directy, using par3d you can get projMatrix and use it to extract the angles.

Comment: @DieterMenne I rotated some plot manually, but projMatrix is not changing.

Answer (score 2):

See the package **rggobi** http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rggobi/index.html

For data visualisation in 3 or even more dimensions, try the package rggobi which makes use of the program ggobi.  It is possible to manipulate the data using the mouse, "brush" data, identify points in the data all while visualizing in a number of dimensions.